# How to change font of TextView?

Tags: android, fonts

I have textview. I could not show japanese characteristics. So downloaded font to Assets/fonts folder. I tried this code

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/ipag.ttf");
    TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

But application not working. What should be changed?

Comment: This piece of code is well as long as the font is within assets folder, so the error must be in other side. I would need more information.

Answer (score 0):

This code has work for me:

first declare the font:

```
Typeface font;
```

second inside the onCreate:
`font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myfont.ttf")`;

third: also inside the onCreate:

```
myTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myTest);
myTest.setTypeface(font);
```

My application can change the languaje and japanesse in one of those, and it works well.
This is the font used:
http://wowslider.com/styles/miso-bold-webfont.ttf.
by the way, the font is inside the Assets folder.